# Why is the reactive Value sometimes not updating in template? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, nuxt.js

I have a simple `h3` tag containing a title that is bound to a reactive data property.
I am fetching the value from a Firestore database and assign it to the data property. When I don't reload and access the page through client-side navigation, everything works fine.
However once I reload the title value gets updated properly (seen in console logs and vue dev tools) but the h3-tag remains empty.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <h3 @click="displayCoursePreview" class="mt-5">{{ titl }}</h3>
</template>

<script>
   props: {
     student: {
         type: Boolean
     }
   },
   watch: {
    rehydrated: {
      // Always triggers once store data is rehydrated (seems to work without any problems)
      immediate: true,
      async handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          await this.getSections();
          return this.getTopics();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      titl: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rehydrated() {
      return this.$store.state.rehydrated; // Equals true once store is rehydrated from local storage
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSections() {
      console.log('running') // Runs every time
      let ref = this.$store.state.courses;

      var cid = this.student
        ? ref.currentlyStudying.cid
        : ref.currentlyPreviewing.cid;

      // Get Course Title
      this.$fireStore
        .collection("courses")
        .doc(cid)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data().name) // Logs correct title every time
          this.titl = doc.data().name;
          this.thumbSrc = doc.data().imgsrc;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
</script>
```

I can't figure out why it sometimes displays the title and sometimes does not. Is there another way to bind `titl` to the content of the `h3`-tag without the `{{}}` syntax?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I have changed the `{{}}` syntax to `v-text` like so:
`<h3 @click="displayCoursePreview" class="mt-5" v-text="titl"></h3>`
And now it works every time, even after a hard reload. Can anyone explain the difference and why this works?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question it looks like you might have a race condition between this component and the store. The watch will only trigger 'getSections' if it sees a change in this.$store.state.rehydrated after it's been mounted, but the store might have completed that before this component got mounted, so then the watch never gets triggered.

Not sure why switching to v-text would have altered this, maybe it allows the component to mount slightly faster so it's getting mounted before the store completes it's rehydration?

Comment: getSections gets triggered everytime, because you are right about the watcher being triggered by the `rehydrated` state, but it is also set to `immediate: true`. Which is why no matter if the store already was rehydrated or not, it still fires the functions on every reload/route change.
I have tested this by inserting `console.log('running')` in `getSections` and it logs it every time, but the title still does not display. The data property is also always being set correctly - I can see this in the Vue Dev tools. It just does not display in the h3 tag for some strange reason.

Comment: @Aside sorry, I missed that 'immediate' flag. The intermittent nature of it does sound timing related... strange one. One other question, the watch function uses this.getTopics() but that's not in the methods shown here, have you just removed it from this snippet for brevity?

Comment: Yes, the actual component is way larger, which is why I just did not include the method for better readability. I am also 100% sure the issue is not related to other parts of the component, as the same issue occurred in another unrelated component as well. Using `v-text` fixed both.